# App does not mute at specified time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

**Update: Finally got around to testing. Didn't work. Changed a bit of code and trying again tomorrow.**

In my MainActivity, I have the program retrieve time data from JSON data and store them into variables. I then call the method and split each of the 6 different timings into hours and minutes and multiply them so they are in terms of milliseconds and then use them in `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`. Here is the MainActivity code:

```
   mPrayerTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.muteButton);
    mPrayerTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new fajrModel();
            new shurooqModel();
            new dhuhrModel();
            new asrModel();
            new maghribModel();
            new ishaModel();


            AlarmManager falarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            AlarmManager salarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            AlarmManager dalarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            AlarmManager aalarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            AlarmManager malarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            AlarmManager ialarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);




            //setting up calender for times.
            Calendar fcal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat fTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                fcal.setTime(fTime.parse(fajr));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Calendar dcal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat dTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                dcal.setTime(dTime.parse(dhuhr));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Calendar scal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                scal.setTime(sTime.parse(shurooq));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Calendar acal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat aTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                acal.setTime(aTime.parse(asr));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Calendar mcal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat mTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                mcal.setTime(mTime.parse(maghrib));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Calendar ical = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat iTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                ical.setTime(iTime.parse(isha));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("fajr", String.valueOf(ical));


            /*FAJR

            */
            falarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fcal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            //SHUROOQ

            salarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            //Dhuhr

            dalarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dcal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            //ASR

            aalarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, acal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            //MAGHRIB

            malarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mcal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            //ISHA
            ialarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ical.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);


        }


    });
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AudioManager silent = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    silent.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}
```

}

It does no such thing. It does mute the phone at those times, and to be able to test it I had to build the APK and put it on my phone and waited until the times specified and nothing happens. Where did I go wrong

TLDR: Code does not mute phone at all, even though it should at specific times.

Comment: Please stop tagging this as Android studio. This has nothing to do with the IDE you are using.

Answer (score 0):

there are two thing I want to remind you:

1、 I suggest you use `SimpleDateFormat` to get hour，minute,second etc. such as :

```
    String minute=new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(date);
```

2、I not have see your code,but ,I know AlarmManager is not execute on time,it will execute at your setting or before,this is in order to save power and since API 19.

Comment: Everywhere I've looked it says to use AlarmManager to do so

Comment: Note from google doc, Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(totalFTime)), pendingIntent);
```

to

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(totalFTime)), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Will do! Whats the difference between `set` and `setExact` if I may ask?

Comment: Please go through foll link        https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)